# WordPress 4.6 had problems with cURL error 23

Tags: wordpress, curl, plugins, wordpress-4.6

After a recent upgrade to WordPress 4.6 had problems with cURL (eg when updating plug-ins that use cURL):
cURL error 23: Failed writing body (373 = 449!)

Judging by the forum, to 4.6 cURL broke, and 4.6.1 are still not rolled out the fix.

The decision to fix the line:

```
if (!function_exists('curl_init') || !function_exists('curl_exec')) {
```

to

```
if (true || !function_exists('curl_init') || !function_exists('curl_exec')) {
```

in ./wp-includes/Requests/Transport/cURL.php file

I don't recommend to edit Wordpress core files but Wordpress Developer have to fix that in next update.

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: that was question but now its with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that PHP was built without curl, not with the source code. if you're compiling PHP yourself make sure to compile with `--with-curl` as described here http://php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php

if you're not compiling yourself, and you're on 1 of those linuxes with package managers, it's probably available through your package manager, for instance, with Ubuntu and Debian: `apt-get install php5-curl` or more recently (debian 9 testing, ubuntu 16.04 for instance) `apt-get install php7.0-curl`

if you're on windows, it's probably available in a DLL that you haven't loaded, add `extension=php_curl.dll` to php.ini

Comment: Thanks for that information. i really appreciate that information because editing Wordpress core files is not a solution. i will contact my hosting.